# PDFBox: how to properly copy annotation from one pdf to another

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to copy annotations from one pdf to another. But copying even 1 annotation DOUBLES the size of outputing pdf file.

Please find below simple code sample:

```
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File("test1.pdf"));
    PDDocument pdf2 = PDDocument.load(new File("test/test1.pdf"));
    List<PDAnnotation> pdfAnnotations1 = pdf.getPage(0).getAnnotations();
    List<PDAnnotation> pdfAnnotations2 = pdf2.getPage(0).getAnnotations();

    pdfAnnotations1.add(pdfAnnotations2.get(0));
    pdf.save("test1.pdf");
```

If I try to open this output file with Adobe Reader and save it again - size comes back to normal. Any thoughts?
Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each annotation points back to the page where it is. So you need to correct that as well by calling `pdfAnnotations1.get(0).setPage(pdf.getPage(0))`.

The size increase is because without the call I described, the annotation will point back to the old page, which points back to its parent, etc.

Comment: Depending on the type of annotation there might be other references into the source document, too, e.g. in case if form fields with a name hierarchy...

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your line of code. Why should we pass annotation as a page? 'setPage' parameter should be instance of PDPage. I understood that we should cut off references to old page, but how to do it properly?

Comment: Unfortunately It isn't given any visible effect. Size is still doubles.

Comment: Can you share the two files and the result file? (And to be sure, save the result file without adding the annotations. In some cases (tagged) PDF files get bigger because PDFBox doesn't support object stream compression)

Comment: This is the first [pdf](https://docdro.id/sF4IRHm), this is the second [pdf](https://docdro.id/8awSdUh), and the result [pdf](https://docdro.id/Bx1zena)

Comment: @TheDiamondDoge As described by Tilman the annotation still points to a copy of the old page it was on, not to the current one. The reason is that there still is an error in the answer; you copy from `pdf2` to `pdf`. Thus, the page you have to set is not `pdf2.getPage(0)` but instead `pdf.getPage(0)`.

Comment: @mkl yes, thanks. I really got confused with the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for all of your time and effort. It finally works.