# PDFBox: FDFDocument not imported

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to copy FDFDocument from one pdf to another. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
  try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\fdf\\dummyPdf1.pdf"))) {

  PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
  FDFDocument fdfDocument = acroForm.exportFDF();

  PDDocument dummyDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\fdf\\dummyPdf2.pdf"));
  dummyDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().importFDF(fdfDocument);

  dummyDocument.save("C:\\Users\\fdf\\dummyPdf3.pdf");
  dummyDocument.close();
}
```

I'm hoping to copy all the form fields that are configured in testPdf to dummyPdf. But, I don't see the form fields are being copied. What am I missing here? is there any other approach to what I need? I'm using `2.0.9` version of pdfbox if that helps.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the current version 2.0.14 and share your files.

Comment: "But, I do see the form fields are being copied" - what were you expecting? That they'd not be copied?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry about the typo. I'm not able to see the properties being copied. Updated the post with screenshot. I couldn't upload the pdfs but it's just one test field with green background which I want to be copied over when I generate third pdf.

Comment: I was hoping either it would replace the field with green box or add new one along side when i generate dummyPdf3.

Comment: PDFBox FDF export is value-only, not appearances, flags, or whatever, not even rich values... Upon import, the value of the field with the matching name is filled..

Comment: I didn't even know we have an fdf export until this question LOL. The better solution is to copy the fields from one PDF to another… however you'll have to adjust the PDPage references of the widgets (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240324/ ). And maybe other things I forgot.